# BS4 Returns on Cloudflare website instead of the actual website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cloudflare

Here is my code. This works, but when the code prints, its printing the DDOS attack website and not the website after that loads. I even tried to do a `time.sleep(5)` to help with timing.

How can I get past that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


url = 'https://www.psacard.com/cert/49628062'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('div'):
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If any parts of the web page is rendered dynamically, for example using `Javascript`, `beautifulsoup` might not be able to work with that.
use `Selenium` for scraping.

Comment: this will not bypass the same error... just tried it.